# Why doesn't my Rails app pick up translations for error messages on the server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I have a Rails 3.2.3 site running on Ruby 1.9.2. I use the rails-i18n gem for translations, and have set the internationalization settings to Dutch translations:

```
config.i18n.available_locales = :nl
config.i18n.default_locale = :nl
```

I've also added the translation file to my locales map, which shouldn't even be required.

When I run the site locally, in development or production mode, all translations are handled correctly, including error messages. However, when I deploy the site to my server (hosted on Webfaction, using nginx), it doesn't use the translations for error messages; they remain to be displayed in English.

I did restart the server, I did precompile, and I "deploy" simply by pulling from github on the server.

Is there anything else I should do in order to make the site use the Dutch translations for erros?

Comment: Silly question, and I know you say you've had it working in production mode locally, but what file is `config.i18n.available_locales = :nl` etc in? In `config\environments\development.rb`? Is it also in `config\environments\production.rb`?

Comment: I'm open to all silly questions at this moment. I've defined these settings in `config\application.rb`, which I believe should be fine.

Comment: Indeed it should. Have you tried setting the locale manually? So in `config\application.rb`, also add `config.i18n.locale = :nl`

Comment: What kind of error messages? Rails validation error messages? Or perhaps some error message from another component? If that's the case it might be possible that an error message from - lets say - an English PostgreSQL installation is bubbling through your application.

Comment: @Russell gave the hint that led to the correct answer, after @Ashitaka pointed out to set `config.i18n.locale = :nl` manually, I set it in production.rb as well (so it's now defined in both application.rb and production.rb). For some reason, the server now uses the Dutch messages too. @Russell, I think you deserve the 50 rep bounty, please post your suggestion to an answer and I'll reward them to you!

@Daniel Rikowski, your suggestion seems valid, but I was talking about Rails validation errors, so this didn't apply.

Comment: Thanks Jasper, very kind of you. Glad you got it resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, from my comment on the question:

> Silly question, and I know you say you've had it working in
>   production mode locally, but what file is
>   `config.i18n.available_locales = :nl` etc in? In
>   `config\environments\development.rb`? Is it also in
>   `config\environments\production.rb`?

It's often easy to forget you've got an option set in one environment but not in another.

Comment: Well I didn't really forget, just setting it in applications.rb should normally be enough, I'd say. However this seemed to help, so if anyone would ever experience similar trouble, this answer might help! Thanks Russell^^

Comment: Yes, I was attempting to try and extract a general hint from it. Glad to help!

Answer (score 2):

The rails-i18n gem includes its own translation files - is it possible that your production environment isn't using the same gemset?

In this case, the solution would be to `bundle update` on the production server.

Alternatively you can either

- copy over the required translation files into config/locales (dutch file is here : https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/nl.yml ).
- use something like [Locale](http://www.localeapp.com) to manage your translation dependencies.

Comment: Good thinking, but this wasn't the case. I had already copied the translation file just to be sure. Locale is a good suggestion, thanks.